# How can I insert the snapshot file during creation of Memgraph container?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm having a problem with ownership of files that are outside of my Memgraph container. I can't find a way to give a ownership attributes to the  file outside of container. I need this to test out the restore process from snapshot backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the snapshot file into the directory after creating the container and start the database. If your folder is called `snapshots` the command should look like this:

```
docker create -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -v `snapshots`:/var/lib/memgraph/snapshots --name memgraphDB memgraph/memgraph
tar -cf - snapshot_file | docker cp -a - memgraphDB:/var/lib/memgraph/snapshots
```

The `snapshot_file` is the snapshot file you want to use to restore the data. Due to the nature of Docker file ownership, you need to use `tar` to copy the file as STDIN into the non-running container. It will allow you to change the ownership of the file to the `memgraph` user inside the container.

After that, start the database with:

```
docker start -a memgraphDB
```

The `-a` flag is used to attach to the container's output so you can see the logs.

Once memgraph is started, change the snapshot directory ownership to the `memgraph` user by running the following command:

```
docker exec -it -u 0 memgraphDB bash -c "chown memgraph:memgraph /var/lib/memgraph/snasphots"
```

If you don't change the ownership Memgraph will not be able to write the future snapshot files and will fail.